# how to transfer user entered data from html to Nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, http

I am new to nodejs and making a site up to 5 to 6 pages and want to know how to transfer entered data by user  from html to Nodejs. If it is a silly question I am sorry for that. Please try to give answer using http module or express.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send AJAX request from HTML pages to the API.
use axios framework to create an http request.